# getting php file to work with crontab

Tags: php, cron

I have a php file that I can run from the browser and it works perfect. I tried to set up a cron job to run the php file, but am obviously missing something.

Since this php file was originally ran from the browser, it is uploaded to the `/var/www` folder. I made a copy of it in a new folder called `/var/cron`. I made this folder just to test.  I will probably put it in another folder, but for now it is in this folder.

Here is what I did. After copying the php file to the `/var/cron` folder, I ran the `crontab -e` command to edit the crontab file. My cron job looks like this:

```
00,30,59 * * * * /var/cron/download.php
```

I have tried changing permissions by using chmod 755 download.php

that didn't do anything.

I have tried `/usr/bin/wget -q /var/cron/download.php`

this didn't do anything either.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you add

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

as the first line of the php file, you can run it from the command line (as long as it has appropriate permissions.  You can test run by going to the directory and typing

```
./download.php
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add that I did try adding that as the first line. I put it before <?php and after. Still didn't work.

Comment: Did you try running it from the command line?  Why didn't it work?  More detail about what exactly went wrong would be helpful.

Comment: I didn't run it from the command line the first time, but try it this time and it ran. The only detail I can give is that it worked from the command line and the cron doesn't seem to be firing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little surprised amccausl's approach didn't work for you.

Have you tried changing your crontab so it looks like this:

```
00,30,59 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/cron/download.php
```

This assumes `/usr/bin/php` is where php lives on your server.

(You may also need to install a "cli" package for PHP, eg. Ubuntu/Debian's `php5-cli`.)

Comment: I added /usr/bin/php to the cron job, but it still doesn't seem to be firing. Installing php5-cli didn't do anything different either. So, this means that it runs from the browser and command line but not the crontab.

Answer (score 1):

Try with full URL like :

```
wget -O - -q "http://www.domain.com/cron.php"
```